# Correct way to feed data to RNN in PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a data sequence `a` which is of shape `[seq_len, 2]`, `seq_len` is the length of the sequence. There is time correlation among elements of `a[:, 0]` and `a[:, 1]`, but `a[:, 0]` and `a[:, 1]` are independent of each other. For training I prepare data of shape `[batch_size, seq_len, 2]`. The initialization of BRNN that I use is

```
birnn_layer = nn.RNN(input_size=2, hidden_size=100, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
```

From the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.RNN.html#torch.nn.RNN),

> input_size – The number of expected features in the input x

> hidden_size – The number of features in the hidden state h

What does "number of expected features" mean? Since there is correlation along the `seq_len` axis should my `input_size` be set as `seq_len` and the input be permuted? Thanks.

Comment: you wrote ```correlation among elements a[:, 0] and a[:, 1], but a[:, 0] and a[:, 1] are independent of each other```. Do you meant a[0][0] and a [0][1] as independent?

Comment: @TheodorPeifer, suppose `a=[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]`, then, `a, c, e` are correlated and `b, d, e` are correlated. But the first set of values do not influence the values taken by the second set of values. In other words, `a, c, e` can be seen as samples from a process and `b, d, e` from another process. The processes are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

The question is how, if at all, your data contributes to the overall optimization problem. You said that elements of `a[:, 0]` are time-correlated and elements of `a[:, 1]` are time-correlated. Are  `a[i, 0]` and `a[i, 1]` time-correlated? Does it makes sense for both sequences to be set together?

If, for example, you are trying to predict whether certain electrical machine is going to malfunction based on sequences of voltage applied to the machine `a[:, 0]` and humidity in the room `a[:, 1]` over time plus these signals were collected at the same time it is ok.  But should they were collected in different time, does it makes sense? Or if you would have measured something different than humidity, would it help you predict malfunction?

***number of expected features*** means number of features in a single timestamp so to speak. So, going along with my previous analogy, how many signals (voltage, humidity.. ) I measure simultanously.

Of course this is only an example, you do not have to have classification-over-time problem, it can be anything else. The bottom point is how your RNN and data work together.

Comment: `a[i, 0]` and `a[i, 1]` are independent for any `i`. Like I mentioned in the comments `a[:, 0]` can seen as samples from a process _A_ and `a[:, 1]` as samples from process _B_, where _A_ doesn't influence _B_.

Comment: @learner I understand that. Thats why I tried to give an example where signals were assumed independent (voltage/humidity). Also I have seen your comment under @Mercury's answer.. Imho you should set `input_size=2` but without the use case and information about what you are trying to do with your network, it's impossible to say.

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is that there are two stochastic processes outputting samples at every sampling time. The samples from a process are correlated. I am trying to teach my BRNN this process evolution and try and make it predict the future values given the current value. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Is the whole pair `[c, d]` time independent from `[a, b]`? If there is a dependency, that is, the data follows a concrete logic that `[c, d]` must occur at a later time or instance than `[a, b]`, then the sequence formulation of `[[a,b], [c,d], ...]` is correct. For your data of the form `batch_size x seq_len x 2`, this `2` would be the "The number of expected features" or the `input_size`.

However, you've also said that `[a, c, e]` and  `[b, d, f]` are results of *independent* processes. So naturally, they can also be separable as two independent sequences of the form `batch_size x seq_len x 1`. You could pass these two sequences through two separate BRNN layers, and then combine the resulting features -- by concatenation along the feature dimension, or by taking sum, average, maximum etc. A bit of light reading on the topic of multimodal fusion in deep learning may be helpful in this regard.

Comment: Suppose I have two processes _A_ and _B_ that start at the same time. At each sampling instant I take one sample from each process to get the tuple `[a, b]`. In the next sampling instant, I get the tuple `[c, d]`. However, the processes _A_ and _B_ are independent. So to answer your question, `[c, d]` _must_ occur after `[a, b]`.

Comment: "You could pass these two sequences through two separate..." yes, but it depends on context, right? So  again, how his data relates to the optimization problem?